# why does swift closure complain there is no init

Tags: swift, closures

I have a handler defined this way:

```
var handler: (String, (Bool) -> Void) -> Void
```

I am passing this in:

```
handler: ((String) -> Void)
                              { a in
                    print(a)
                }
```

I get this error and I don't understand how to fix it.

```
Type '(String) -> Void' has no member 'init'
```

When I tried this way I got the same error but I don't think it is correct as the handler passes in another closure with the boolean.

```
handler: (String, (Bool) -> Void) -> Void)
                              { a in
                    print(a)
                }
```

[image: Error message and code screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue there is that the closure expects two parameters:

```
var handler: (String, (Bool) -> Void) -> Void = { _,_  in }
```

---

```
handler = { a, b in
    print(a)
    b(false)
}
```

---

```
handler("a") { bool in print(bool) }
```

This will print:

> a
> false

Comment: Thanks. I kept trying different thoughts, didn't pass in to have it call b, I tried to have it print out the value of b.